# Why build a mech drone?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, technology, warfare

In *Halo*, there are large mechanized suits called [Mantises](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/HRUNTING/YGGDRASIL_Mark_IX_Armor_Defense_System). These are heavily armed and bipedal (kind of like the the AT-ST). There is no doubt that they *can* be built, but why would they? What would the advantages be of a bipedal mech suit?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The page you linked says that they're about 5.7 meters (18.8 feet) tall. My immediate thought is that this height advantage should be used. The operator of the drone would need to use it to face enemies that are pretty big.

Potential victims:

- Large aliens that could rip a human in half
- Large military/armored vehicles
- Other large mech suits
- Large animals (maybe we're waging a war on elephants)

A human - even a heavily armed one - would have problems taking one of these enemies down. A mech suit would have it easier.

Comment: A tank would have it even easier, and would cost probably less.

Comment: @vsz For a tank you need a driver, a gunner, a loader and a tank commander, while a mech can be oprated by a single person.

Comment: @Hexaholic The amount of automation required for a mech to be operated by a single person could just as easily be applied to a tank (probably easier, in fact).

Answer (score 9):

Mech suites are great, but bipeds are a bit iffy

Three reasons why:

- Use tools built for humans: A human shaped mech suite with human shaped hands would not require redesigning tools or weapons for the mech to be able to wield or use
- Intuitive to operate for complex actions: Human drivers have years of experience operating human shaped bodies so it would be more simple to teach them how to do very complex moves in a biped.
- Move through human shaped spaces: The stairs, doors and ladders of our world are shaped for easy use by humans, not mechs on tank treads maybe the need to move in human shaped spaces is enough.

Why not:

- Bipeds are slow: The record speed of mechanical or [organic bipeds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fastest_animals) is 60 mph, the current record speed for [wheeled vehicles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_speed_record) is 763.035 mph.  You are 10 times slower for being a biped.
- Bipeds are unstable: A quadruped or a hexapod can walk in a statically stable manner. If frozen at any time it would be balanced and upright. A biped must be constantly leaning or stepping to keep balance. For examples, look at the recent [DARPA robotics competition](http://www.theroboticschallenge.org).

Comment: Why are those the max speeds? Can you give references? Ostriches can supposedly run 43mph. Also, is comparing a biped to a wheeled vehicle relevant? They are really very different things.

Comment: I had the wrong number 28.3 is the current record speed of a mechanical quadruped the cheetah, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=chPanW0QWhA.  The animal cheetah is 75 mph and ostrich is 43 mph.  The current record for wheeled vehicle from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_speed_record is 760 mph for wheeled and 403 for wheel driven.  I will edit its a factor of ten not thirty.

Comment: I don't think MaxSpeed really applies. If I want to compare the speed of a War-Mech, I don't use a racing car, I use a tank (or ATV, or ...). Despite from that, tanks are still fast.

Comment: Speed comparison here is a bit flawed here, because it doesn't account for the terrain. On a street a wheeled vehicle is, without doubt, much faster, but there is a reason why tanks and other armoured vehicles are rarely used in mountainous terrain for example.

Comment: @Bounce even on rough terrain bipeds are slower than quadrupeds.  A mountain goat out runs a human, a cheetah out runs an ostrich.  You could design terrain that is only traversable by bipeds (think a ladder in a small vertical shaft)  But that is what I was talking about in the point on human shaped spaces.

Comment: @J_F_B_M Fair point I was trying to quickly explain the speed advantages, there is today no biped equivalent to a main battle tank so I couldn't make that comparison.  So I compared speed on animals/vehicles that are optimized for speed.  This was faster then a detailed examination of mechanical efficiencies, the square cube law, and the other core reasons for inefficient biped locomotion.

Comment: @sdrawkcabdear: That depends. A human is faster and more secure in climbing a mountain than a dog, for example. Also, I referred to your comparison between bipeds and wheeled vehicle.

Comment: @Bounce Do you have numbers on the human dog comparison?  Even on a steep slope a wheeled vehicle can out run a biped and on a cliff face humans act as quadrupeds not bipeds.  The special terrains where only bipeds can go are rare in nature, if you go anywhere else don't use a biped.  You are insisting on a comparison only in these special spaces, not common spaces like towns, cities, forests.  This speed comparison is supposed to show mechanical efficiencies without explaining the underling issues like acceleration and deceleration costs and the square cube law.

Comment: @sdrawkcabdear: No, just personal experience ;). What I wanted to express with this example is, that also the flexibility plays a role. Of course, with modern technology and robotics, there are more efficient ways than bipedal, especially if you design the vehicle for certain purposes (which is mostly the case). Want a street runner? --> wheeled. Want off-road? --> tank track. Want a climber? --> legs and arms (how many? We'd have to try ;) ). Want an heavy armored human? --> biped suit (because human are biped ^^)

Comment: Bipedal mechs usually assume a near human level of maneuverability. So compare a human walking/running to a human in a motorized wheelchair. Which one is more maneuverable? In a straight line the wheelchair may be faster, but in almost every other capacity the biped has the advantage. Of course this presumes the wheel/tread stay static while bipedal locomotion advances, versus something like Stephenson's "smartwheel" from Snow Crash.

Comment: @JasonK It depends what you mean by maneuverability.  If you take it as acceleration the wheeled vehicle with clobber the biped (you can build a motorized wheel chair that will out accelerate Usain bolt).  If you are talking about turning speed a wheeled vehicle also will win for a given speed if it is designed to turn tightly (cars are not designed to turn tightly they only rotate one set of wheels, they also usually turn while moving 40 -60 mph bipeds only turn while going 20 mph because that is their max speed)  What are the other capacities you speed of?  Caring capacity fuel efficiency?

Comment: @sdrawkcabdear Take for instance, the bipedal ability to side step, bob back and forth, climb stairs, jump, crouch down (or possibly lay down), etc. I think it would be extremely difficult to make a suspension and control system for a tracked or wheeled vehicle to do all this. Just watch folks in wheelchairs try to navigate through tight spaces. Humans can do this almost effortlessly since we can shift weight and alter foot placement. Mecha are typically given this same 'grace', especially the very humanoid ones. Obviously some, like the AT-ST or AT-AT, are a bit more "lumbering".

Comment: Many of these have been beaten, Boston dynamics has a wheeled robot that can jump more than 10x its height. You could make a robot that has a wheeled chest that could move 20 mph while lying down.  I think the wheel chair comparison is a bit misleading for 2 reasons, wheel chairs are trying to navigate spaces designed for smaller bipeds. There are few staircases and buildings that are large enough for any mecha to navigate, since no mocha could navigate them the fact that a wheeled one would have trouble is not really relevant.  Talk to me about how an atv preforms in the hills or forests.

Comment: @JasonK also read my response I explicitly call outa major advantage of mechs would be their ability to use and operate in human shaped spaces, assuming those spaces are large enough.

Comment: @sdrawkcabdear I don't think the maneuvering advantage is limited to "human shaped spaces though". Consider popping around rock formations, between buildings, etc. Vehicles lack much of a lateral movement ability (even tanks that can rotate within their own footprint) that could be a huge benefit in combat. As for the "Sand Flea", I'm not sure how scalable that jumping mechanism is, and those big fat wheels are going to be mobility kills right away :) It does illustrate that future locomotion systems will probably be VERY different from what we are speculating on now.

Comment: And, FWIW, Heavy Gear from Dream Pod 9 (mech RPG) has wheels in the feet of the mechs (kind of like those shoe/rollerskate things kids use) that would give them flat ground speed similar to a wheeled vehicle. Hybrid locomotion is definitely worth considering.

Answer (score 5):

The number one answer is they would be super cool especially in animation.

Another reason would be fast movement over unpaved terrain. Obviously, our tech is not there but if you wanted to get up and over bombed out buildings and what not being able to climb over them would be a boon. A better design for this would include hands or be a goat-bot.  If the desire was to Run Ostrich style across broken roads guns a blazing the mech shown could be a solution.

But looking cool would be the best reason.

Comment: "looking cool would be the best reason."  Yep.  But this doesn't necessarily make it irrelevant to battle.  The psychological effect of your weapon on the enemy is important.

Comment: "Aw shet, they brought the Deathstalker mechs out again. We gotta get out of here!"